# Регулярка - из строки "100 Долар США 1196.3280" нужно выделить "1196.3280"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста сделать регулярку для поиска последней цифры из строки

```
100           Долар США            1196.3280
```

нужно выделить 1196.3280

Comment: Разбейте строку по знаку табуляции \t и возьмите последний элемент массива

Comment: где то так

    \d+\s+.*\s+(\d+(:?\.\d+)?)

Правда, в случае регулярных выражений всегда нужно уточнять, какой именно движок регулярок используется.

Answer (score 1):

На случай если последнее число будет целым:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
```

Comment: тогда уж `(\d+\.\d+)$`